# "command not found issue" in Terminal installing cocoa pods

Tags: xcode, terminal, osx-yosemite, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I initialise pod in my terminal command not found issue occurs...please tell me solution

here is [my terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aG7Q.png)

Comment: Looks like you are using Acadmeia > pod install. It should just be pod install.

Comment: I am getting the same issue.  On macOS, I open terminal, go to XCode project directory and attemp $ pod init and I get the "command not found" error.  Need path to pod bash script maybe?